# How to reloadData in class which implements UITableViewDataSource protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reloaddata, uitableview

I have a class which implements UITableViewDelegate protocol and there is another class which handles data i.e. it implements UITableViewDataSource protocol.

```
@interface TableViewClass : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@interface TableDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>
```

and I'm setting the TableViewClass as delegate and TableDataSource as datasource

```
id datasource = [[TableDataSource alloc] init]
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:dataSource];
```

I am fetching the data off an asynchronous server call in init method of TableDataSource class which populates an array and determines the number of rows/sections in table.

But before the call returns back some result, the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are executed resulting in 0 rows and 0 sections, hence an empty table.

I thought of putting the `[self.tableView reloadData]` in callBack but I do not have access to tableView in datasource class.
Can anybody guide me how to reloadData in tableView through datasource class as I might need it later to refresh data too.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this quickly, you can add an @property on TableDataSource for the UITableView.

```
// TableDataSource.h
@interface TableDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView *tableView;
}

@property(retain)UITableView *tableView;

@end

// TableDataSource.m
@implementation TableDataSource
@synthesize tableView;

- (void)dealloc{
    self.tableView = nil;
}

@end
```

Now, set the property when you create the DataSource:

```
// UITableViewController.m
TableDataSource* datasource = [[TableDataSource alloc] init]
[datasource setTableView:self.tableView]
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:dataSource];
```

When you need to reload the data from the DataSource, you can now do:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```